# Google chrome keeps crashing: possible conflict with comodo firewall?

Tags: google-chrome, firewall, crash, software-conflict, comodo-firewall

I've used chrome for years, and comodo firewall and HIPS protection for some months, but suddenly google chrome started crashing as soon as it was loaded.
I tried to reset my user profile and reinstall the program, but nothing changed, and loading it in Comodo sandbox didn't lead to any results.
I noticed that in temporary mode, chrome crashed only after some seconds.
Today I installed Comodo Dragon (which should be a modified version of google chrome), and it worked perfectly. So I tried to run google chrome in comodo sandbox, and it actually started, but I saw the message "aw, snap" for every page I tried to load. I clicked on "More info" and saw that comodo firewall is known to enter in conflict with chrome. So I temporarly disabled it, but chrome kept crashing.
Now chrome doesn't start anymore even in comodo sandbox.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the chrome debug file in the location "**AppData\Local\Google\CrashReports"** and debug it using windbg for the exact crash result.

```
Run chrome exe using 
1) windbg.exe -o chrome.exe
2) try loading the page and make chrome to crash.
3.) Create full crash dump using .dump /ma C:\Path\File.dmp 
4.) end session and load the crash dump with windbg
5.) use !analyze -v to extract valuable information
```

If the above is not an option for you to proceed please follow the chromium link below from steps regarding issue reporting.

http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug